# Php find out what type of hash is a string

Tags: php, hash

I have a hash, how can I find out the type of that hash sha1, md2, md5 or other() ?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Only way I can think of if checking hash length - SHA1 is 160 bit, MD5 is 128 bit just as MD2.

Comment: I have a hash like string that is 35 bytes length...

Comment: 35 bytes or 35 chars?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to find out for sure, which algorithm was used to generate a hash value. If you can restrict the set of hash functions, you might be lucky by examining the length of the hash value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to find out for sure and it will be hard to work it out.  Because these are one way methods so by nature they should be hard to crack/work out the method used.

My advice is to look through the source code if you have access to it or contact the owner of the code.  Another option is if you have the original string (before being hased) you can run it through hashing function until you find a match but it sounds like that's not possible.

Comment: Hash functions are not encryption functions.

Comment: I'ved edited my answer so it made more sense, thanks